# How to deal with tags in a component

Tags: unity, component-based

I have a component called "ReflectOffCollision". This component should obviously not need to be aware of specific details about the game such as tags. The problem is, I want to apply this script to an object that reflects off of only some collisions.

I could check the tag of the collision, but this will destroy the generality of the component. It will only work on collisions with this tag. I could have the script take a white list or black list of tags, but this is awkward to do.

My other option is to inherit from the component and make a more specific version. This seems like overkill, though.

How should I deal with tags in components? I see this problem anywhere that there are collisions. Am I using tags incorrectly, or misunderstanding them?

Comment: Does your object (which has this script) collide "normally" with Objects which would not trigger this Script?

Comment: Yeah. In this particular case, I want this object to reflect off of the level mesh, but behave differently when colliding with a player object.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to achieve this. First, you can use layers and modify the collision matrix so that it won't interact with non-collidable objects. Second, objects you want to collide can contain a common component to mark them as collidable.

Let's say it's Reflectable. At run-time, you can determine whether the object is collidable or not with this:

```
if(collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Reflectable>()!=null)
    collide();
```

Comment: Wouldn't that just be an empty component that now has to be added to everything that's reflectable just for the sake of doing this?

Comment: Yes, it would be an empty component. However, you can define a Movable base class and implement isReflectable() method and derive your controller classes from it also.